# How to find a pair of divisors as close as possible to each other?

Tags: algorithms

For a given integer $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, I want to find a pair $(x,y)\in{\mathbb{N}^*}^2$ such that $x*y=n$ and $|y-x|$ is as small as possible.

A naive algorithm I found is :

```
for k = floor(sqrt(n)) to 1 step -1
  if n/k is integer then
    return (k, n/k)
  end if
end for
```

Although I am almost certain there is a more efficient way to do this, I cannot find one.

Comment: Actually, the closer pair should be the numbers as close to $\sqrt{n}$ as possible.

Comment: @Ertxiem True, but it doesn't help me to find a better solution. This is actually what my naive algorithm uses: it starts at $\sqrt{n}$ and check every integer down to 1 until it finds a divisor

Comment: $x$ and $y$ must be (products of) prime factors of $n$. Rather than trying every integer, you should just find all prime factors and  then consider their products. At least for large numbers, that will be vastly faster than trying all numbers.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Although your argument is totally valid, complexity-wise, I think that the prime factorization would already outweigh Annyo's initial algorithm.

Comment: @Annyo I was agreeing with you, that you should start from $\sqrt{n}$ downwards.

Comment: Another trick that may be useful is the following, although I cannot see a complete solution based on it: if the two divisors are of the form $a+b$ and $a-b$, then $a^2-b^2=n$. So you may want to test if $n+b^2$ is a perfect square for small values of $b$. There are some parity issues to consider, though, since two arbitrary integers can be written as $a\pm b$ iff they have the same parity, so this idea will probably work out better for odd $n$.

Comment: MWE of OPs approach: https://godbolt.org/z/rEaeYohPh

Answer (score 1):

Note that although there could be more efficient algorithms, what you found is not a bad algorithm. I will analyze this a little bit.

Let us write down the problem formally as a constrained discrete optimization problem:
$$
(x^\star, y^\star) = \arg\min_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z_{+}}} \Big(E \triangleq \big(y-x\big)^2 + \lambda(x*y - n)^2 \Big)
$$
Note that for positive integers the $L_2$ norm will attain the same minimum as $L_1$. So I'll stick to it. $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier and the right-most term is the non-linear constraint. Even if we can compute the partial derivatives and use the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), the problem is not easy to solve due to the parameters restricted to a discrete space. Hence we will **relax** the integer constraint to real numbers and solve the problem for $\mathbb{R}$. The [relaxed optimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_(approximation)) would be attained as follows:
$$
x^\star = \arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \Big(\tilde{E} \triangleq \big(x-\frac{n}{x}\big)^2 \Big)
$$
We achieved this by substitution the constraint : $y \gets \frac{n}{x}$. Note that this is also suggested by the Largange optimization:
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \lambda} = xy - n^2 = 0 \implies x=\frac{n}{y} \text{ or } y=\frac{n}{x}.
$$

Now differentiating w.r.t. $x$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d \tilde{E}}{dx} = 2\big(x-\frac{n}{x}\big) &= 0\\
x^2 &= n \\
x = \sqrt{n}
\end{align}
$$
gives the optimal solution for the relaxed problem. For negative numbers $x = -\sqrt{n}$ is also the optimum. This we could already detect from the sign of the input. Having solved the relaxed problem, a typical optimizer would operate by projecting the solution into the feasible set and/or applying a projected gradient descent. The initial feasible solution is $x_0 = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rceil$. $\lfloor \cdot \rceil$ is the rounding operation or in fancy words the projection onto the integers. From here, it is possible to walk on the Euclidean discrete manifold of 1-dimensional integers by your method: taking steps of $+1$ or $-1$ depending on the direction. That would amount to a gradient descent by the step size $h=1$.

And these steps are what you are following implicitly when arriving at the algorithm you proposed. Unfortunately, the worst case complexity of this algorithm is attained when the number is prime and we have only 2 divisors: $1$ and $n$, the number itself. Therefore, the worst case complexity reaches to $O(\sqrt{n})$. As $n\rightarrow \infty$, this would resemble a linear search (it is worse than $\log$). Now, the set of integers is a [totally ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). Using this property, instead of using a linear search, one could think of a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) variant. But as clarified by @WolfgangBangerth, such an algorithm would not exist bounding the complexity in: $O(\log(\sqrt{n}))<C\leq O(\sqrt{n})$.

Even though this might not be the exact answer you were looking for, I thought it would give a perspective to develop better solutions. For instance, the [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) community might have a better solution.

Comment: This answer uses a lot of complicated words, but it doesn't really provide anything useful. First, the formulation above is not a Lagrangian formulation for the optimization problem (in which case the constraint would appear linearly, not quadratically). Secondly, the whole formulation doesn't yield anything we don't already know: That among the real numbers, $n$ factors into $\sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{n}$. We don't need a complicated formulation for this.

Comment: Third, the speculation of there being a binary search algorithm that is faster really can't be true: If there *were* such an algorithm, then factoring large numbers into primes would be easy. But it isn't. And so such an algorithm can't exist. With the algorithm as shown, you really can't avoid the ${\cal O}(\sqrt{n})$ complexity. The only way around it is a smarter algorithm to find the prime factors (for example, if your numbers are small enough that you can use a table of all prime numbers up to $\sqrt{n}$) and then use those (because there are far fewer prime factors than $\sqrt{n}$).

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, I fully agree that it doesn't say anything new. I even wrote this in my response that I would not be answering the question. But it can provide a perspective to the author of the question in seeking new possibilities. If $O(\log(n))$ is unachievable, then at least we know the complexity is bounded $O(\log(n))<C\leq O(\sqrt{n})$ up to some scalars.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, And with all due respect, I'm not a mathematician so please enlighten me on this: What makes the method of Lagrange multipliers require a linear constraint? I believed eq. 1 can describe a constrained problem. $E$ is indeed a function of $\lambda$ and both the data term and the constraints have continuous first partial derivatives.

Comment: If you square the constraint, you get a degenerate problem that does not satisfy the LICQ (the Linear Independence Constraint Qualification). The problem does then not, in general, have a unique Lagrange multiplier at the optimality point.

Comment: While being non-unique, a solution (one of them) could be computed though?

Comment: Violating the LICQ is generally a bad idea with all sorts of bad consequences. One of them being that there may be no Lagrange multiplier at all, and in that case the first order optimality conditions $\partial L/\partial x=0$ may not be satisfied at all at the optimum.

Answer (score 1):

As @FedericoPoloni commented on the post above, a natural way to expedite this search (relative to simple descending trial division) is by [Fermat's Factorization Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124080/fermat-factorization).  As [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method) illustrates, the Fermat approach can take bigger steps than trial division, but at a cost of more arithmetic (square roots in extended precision versus only integer division).

Fermat's idea is to search for a difference of integers squares $N = a^2 - b^2$, so that $N = (a + b)(a - b)$.  If the search starts with $a \ge \sqrt N$, then incrementally increasing $a$ finds the first *such* pair of "cofactors" of $N$, $c = a+b, d = a-b$ as close together as possible.  CAVEAT: The cofactor pair $c,d$ would then have the same parity!

This means that we may either (i) *not* be able to express $N$ as a difference of two integer squares (in the case that $N = 4k+2$) or (ii) find a pair of same parity cofactors which are not the desired closest together pair of cofactors.  An example of the first problem is $N=6$, which is not a difference of integer squares as shown in answers to [this older Math.SE Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247853/proving-expressibility-of-integers-as-the-difference-of-two-squares).

An example of the second problem is $N=12$, which can be expressed as a difference of squares $12 = 4^2 - 2^2 = 6\cdot 2$, but whose closest cofactors are instead $12 = 4\cdot 3$ (and not of the same parity).

Of course if $N$ is odd, it has only odd divisors, so any two cofactors will be the same parity (odd).  To handle the case when $N$ is even, one can apply Fermat's method to $4N$.  Now if we locate a cofactor pair of the same parity, they will *both* be even!  So we will have $4N = (2c)(2d)$, and hence $N = cd$.  Furthermore our search will locate the closest same parity cofactors $2c,2d$ of $4N$.  It follows that $c,d$ are the closest cofactor pair of $N$ (though not necessarily of the same parity).

If $N$ is odd, then while a correct result will obtain from applying Fermat to $4N$, there is an advantage to applying directly to $N$.  The oddness of $N$ means that numbers of the form $4k+1$ will be expressed as an odd square minus an even square, so our search is limited to checking $a$ odd.  On the other hand numbers of the form $4k-1$ will be an even square minus an odd square, and again our search is limited (to checking $a$ even).

**Algorithm:** Fermat's Factorization Method (FFM)

Given as input positive integer $N \ge 1$ which is odd or a multiple of $4$:

0. Initialize integer $a = \lceil \sqrt N \rceil$.  If $a = \sqrt N$, stop. OUTPUT: The closest cofactors are $c = d = \sqrt N$.  Otherwise:
1. Now $a^2 > N$, so compute $a^2 - N$ and $b = \lfloor \sqrt{a^2 - N} \rfloor$. If $b = \sqrt{a^2 - N}$, stop.  OUTPUT: The closest (same parity) cofactors are $c = a + b, d = a - b$.  Otherwise:
2. Increment $a$ suitably (parity consideration) and go to Step 1.

---

It is possible to analyze at what point trial division becomes as efficient as Fermat's method, due to its trade-off of step size versus complexity.  I plan to do an extended precision implementation, with the speculation that the time required for Fermat's step is about three times the time needed for trial division.